# What's wrong with having a nested class as ModelAttribute in a Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a simple form that retrieve 3 information from users (**String name, MultipartFile img, List types**).
But as these objects are not tied to a specific bean, I created a nested class in my Controller called **MyForm** (because I wouldn't use it elsewhere) that goes like this:

```
// this is inside a controller
public class MyForm {
    private String name;
    private MultipartFile img;
    private List<Type> types;

    public MyForm() {}

    public MyForm(String name, Multipart img, List<Type> types) {
         this.name = name;
         this.img = img;
         this.types = types
    }
}
```

the method of my controller that uses it is as follow :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveSomeObject(@ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm myForm,  ModelMap map,
                              BindingResult result){
    SomeObject c = new SomeObject();
    c.setName(myForm.getName());
    c.setTypes(myForm.getTypes());
    doSomethingWithTheImage(myForm.getImg());

   //...
```

the issue face is that when the form is submitted and saveSomeObject is called, I got an error saying `No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.main.statisthira.controllers.MyController.MyForm.<init>()` (though I do have a default constructor, with no args)

but then I moved the MyForm class outside the MyController class, and everything worked.
So I just want to know if it is just bad design or if something else caused that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least your inner class is not declared `static` (will hold a reference to the outer controller instance, see also [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)). By this you need an instance of the controller to create a form which is not possible to be done by the MVC framework. Declaring it static should resolve the problem.